# Poor Linux IP tunnel performance

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, tunnel

I'm attempting to setup a protocol 41 tunnel between 2 networks over the internet using the Linux ip6tnl interface. Running iperf between the 2 networks directly over the internet results in around 900Mbps which is what it should be. Running through the tunnel I lose about 80% of my throughput and the link is crippled down to 200Mbps. I have tried both no encapsulation and udp encapsulation using fou but the performance is the same either way. I am creating the tunnel with the default settings. See the commands I'm using below.

Without encapsulation:
`ip l a test type ip6tnl local 2001:db8::1 remote 2001:db8:1::1 mode ip6ip6`

With UDP encapsulation:
`ip l a test type ip6tnl encap fou encap-sport 5555 encap-dport 5555 local 2001:db8::1 remote 2001:db8:1::1 mode ip6ip6`

I have tried lowering the tunnel MTU to 1280 just to make sure it wasn't some weird PMTUD issue but it didn't change the results at all. What could cause the massive performance drop and what can be done to mitigate it?

Comment: Does it affect other tunnel types, e.g. GRE (more widely used than raw v6-over-v6), or even WireGuard (which uses different kernel infrastructure)? Can you test direct (non-tunnel) UDP throughput to rule out the Internet link throttling non-TCP or such?

Comment: @user1686 interestingly enough it does not appear to affect GRE, I don't know how to test regular UDP? iperf over UDP gives similarly limited performance...even inside the GRE tunnel so I'm not positive it's an issue with UDP(at least not an ISP one). ISP for reference is AT&T residential gigabit fiber

Comment: There might be better tools but iperf3 has a UDP mode (without flow control; you need to specify the "expected" rate using -b). It might not be that, though.

Comment: @user1686 yeah, I tried iperf3 with -ub0 and I got the same performance inside GRE as outside GRE which is about 200Mbps. Even doing -ub600M yields the same. TCP iperf3 is about 880Mbps inside GRE. Putting GRE inside the FOU also results in about 200Mbps throughput. Maybe I should try wireguard, that's a bit more effort to configure but I'm not entirely sure what else to test...maybe vxlan? Is it common for ISPs to throttle UDP? I could understand protocol 41 but UDP seems like a weird one, especially if GRE isn't.

Comment: @user1686 ...I found my problem...it's vultr...I hate this host so much, I have had so many network issues since I started using them a month ago I should've known it was them but I didn't even think about it since my TCP performance was fine. If they didn't have the 1 feature I needed I'd cancel my account and run like hell. I'll post an answer to this not that it'll really help anyone in the future.

Comment: For what it's worth, manual WireGuard setup is not too different from GRE or FOU: `ip link add wg0 type wireguard && wg set wg0 listen-port 5555 private-key <path> && wg set wg0 peer <pubkey> endpoint [2001:db8:1::1]:5555 allowed-ips ::/0,0.0.0.0/0`. I'm not sure what Vultr is doing with it, but sometimes it happens that e.g. CPEs corrupt UDP checksums (apparently that happens with verizon) or that NICs have broken UDP hardware offload or that ISPs throttle all of UDP as "bittorrent".

Comment: @user1686 no...it's 100% just vultr, I tried one of my other servers in the same datacenter and it just works, just fine, full Gbps. When I first spun up a server with them I had this EXACT issue but with all traffic, not just UDP and I had to contact support and have them move me to a less chatty part of the datacenter, this new server only did it with UDP and so I just assumed it wasn't the server...it was, that original server works great with UDP. Thanks for the info about wg tho. I don't typically use it much.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was on the side of the server host I was attempting to establish the tunnel with. Testing against a different server from the same host or a different host entirely completely resolved the issues.